# Copying values from multiple excel files to a single one with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder with multiple excel files, with values in columns a-g and I want to copy them in a single excel file.

I have tried the following piece of code:

```
`  import os
    import pandas as pd

   # Specify the input folder containing Excel files
    input_folder = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/FilesToProcess'

   # Create an empty DataFrame to store the selected data
    selected_data = pd.DataFrame()

   # Loop through all Excel files in the input folder
    for file_name in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if file_name.endswith('.xlsx'):
   # Read in the Excel file and select the desired columns
    df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(input_folder, file_name), usecols='A:G')
   # Append the selected data to the main DataFrame
    selected_data = selected_data.append(df)[df.columns.tolist()]

   # Specify the output file name and sheet name
    output_file = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/output1.xlsx'
    output_sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

   # Write the selected columns to a new Excel file
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file) as writer:
    selected_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=output_sheet_name, index=False)`
```

Although it works as intended at first, after a couple of files it messes up the columns. Specifically, it begins to copy values in columns > G. I can't show a result example, due to the nature of the data.

Comment: Besides using `append` (*that is deprecated*), selecting the columns twice and having incorrect indentation, what makes you say that sometimes the values of the column `H` for *e.g*, are concatenated as well in your final DataFrame ? It would be helpful if you can share a little screenshot to see how look like the header of the new `Sheet1`. Can you `print(selected_data.columns)` right after the loop exit ? Does the issue occur only with a specific file, a specific column, a bunch of files/columns .. ? Anyways, you need to give more details!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you have some columns in some files that do not follow your standard. For example, some excel files might have "Column1" while others might have a column name of "Column 1" or "Column1 ". This will cause pandas to create new columns when you concatenate and will leave some of the columns empty in some rows.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, however, I found a solution, kinda stupid, but it works. I transformed all excel files into csv, then copied them into one big csv file, then turned it back into excel. Thanks for your help anyway.